# Restrict uploading document with same name sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

how could we restrict users from uploading document with same name in SharePoint Online. In Sharepoint OnPremise, we did it by updating upload.aspx page. As we cant update upload.aspx in Sharepoint Onine, looking out for different options to implement our task.

I was thinking of adding rest api code in EditForm.aspx to check if document already exists or not. but I think it will return true as sharepoint would have uploaded the document till we reach editform.aspx which opens after upload.aspx. Any help would be appreciated.

Please note Its SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

You may considering use [SPRemoteEventResult.CancelWithError] or [SPRemoteEventResult.CancelNoError] to prevent uploading files.

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelNoError;
result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;

using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
{
    if (clientContext != null)
    {
        clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}

//result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelNoError;
result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;
result.ErrorMessage = "Hello World";
return result;
}
```

More reference:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-a-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins
- https://github.com/pnp/PnP/blob/master/Samples/Core.AppEvents.HandlerDelegation/Core.AppEvents.HandlerDelegationWeb/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc.cs

BR